# Qatar Airways second seat selection after paying for the first one

Tags: online-resources, applications, seating, qatar-airways

I have booked a ticket on Qatar Airways for economy class and made a successful seat reservation for one of four flights and paid using paypal. Because of private issues I wanted to book the seating for another flight two days later.

I was able to select my preferred seat but wasn't able to complete the reservation because now the button to reach the website for payment is missing.

Does anybody have the same issue or a solution?

[image: Button for redirection to payment methods missing]

Comment: Have you tried deleting cookies on the webpage or using another browser?

Comment: Yes, it sadly didn't work using icognito mode, another browser or by using the app. The result is always the same.